# How to disable Ale if PAGER mode is enabled

Tags: plugin-ale, pager

I use both [Ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/) and VIM [pager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager) plugins. But for obvious reasons I want to disable some Vim features and plugins in the "less" mode.

But if I put as recommended this piece of code in my `.vimrc` it still starts Ale:

```
if exists('g:vimpager.enabled')
   set nospell
   let g:ale_enabled = 0
endif
```

And if I start vimpager with `vimpager some_file.py` it will still show Ale error and warning messages

Comment: It works for me, your snippet disable ALE correctly. Does the `set nospell` part works? Maybe it is not executed in the right order in your config. To make sure, it should be placed in a file in the `.vim/after/` directory, e.g. inside `.vim/after/plugin/vimpager.vim` or also maybe in `.vimpagerrc`.

Comment: @perelo no, `set nospell` doesn't work either. I added it here as an additional check if it is called.

Comment: I believe this happens to early. When your vimrc file is loaded, your plugins are not loaded so `g:vimpager.enabled` isn't set yet. You can try wrapping this into a VimEnter autocommand, but you most likely need an explicit command to disable Ale, since it will be already loaded at this time.

Comment: Have you tried using `let g:ale_enabled = 0` in `~/.vimpagerrc` or `~/.vim/vimpagerrc` instead?

Comment: @filbranden If I put it in ~/.vimpagerrc it will not load the rest of the options that are set in ~/.vimrc. These are mutually exclusive for vimpager it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the vimpager initialization. Before it was stated that initialization of the plugin should be done by adding these lines in the `.vimrc`:

```
let g:vimpager = {}
let g:less = {}
let g:vimpager.passthrough = 0
```

But and the check for the `g:vimpager.enabled` occured later in the VIMRC file. Obviously the value of `g:vimpager` was reset by this point, rendering the check useless.
So the right way would be to write :

```
if !exists('g:vimpager')
    let g:vimpager = {}
endif
if !exists('g:less')
    let g:less = {}
endif
let g:vimpager.passthrough = 0
...
if !exists('g:vimpager.enabled')
    Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
endif
```

Note the disabling the inclusion of the Ale plugin completely - it speeds up the loading considerably, compared to just setting `let g:ale_enabled = 0`.
The documentation for vimpager plugin was fixed in  [e887ecc](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager/commit/e887ecc0ec75102c27f4d582cb7ed53742f49cfe)  commit.

Answer (score 0):

To quote the docs:

> To disable loading plugins, put "set noloadplugins" into a vimpagerrc file.

Vimpagerrc can be `~/.vimpagerrc` or (recommended for version control) `~/.vim/vimpagerrc` or in the file named by the value of the environment variable `VIMPAGER_RC`

You could also try putting

```
let g:ale_enabled = 0
```

in the vimpagerrc as filbranden suggests.

Comment: I don't want to disable all plugins - some of them are quite useful. Just limit some particular ones.

Comment: If I put it in `~/.vimpagerrc` it will not load the rest of the options that are set in `~/.vimrc`. These are mutually exclusive for vimpager it seems.